# Is it necessary to exit the process after cron job done?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using GKE cron job and Node.js. I am doubt that is it necessary to exit the process after cron job done? I know GKE will destroy the pod after the cron job done.

Here is my code:

```js
try {
      await job();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Run ${context.jobName} cron job failed.`);
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }

process.exit(0)
```

And, I found another issue. If you use `@google_cloud/logging-winston`, if you exit the process after cron job done. It will throw an error:

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission at Object.exports.createStatusError (/app/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28) at InterceptingListener._callNext (/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42) at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8) at callback (/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)

I guess `@google_cloud/logging-winston` try to log but the pod is destroyed.

Using `console.log`, the error gone. I guess `@google_cloud/logging-winston` log asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your application is exiting before winston could write file log. We resolve this issue in cron tasks by adding a sleep at the end of execution to ensure winston had finished.

Also, winston provide a logger.on('finish') event that is triggered when all pending logs has been writted. To work with finish event you need to invoke logger.end() at the end of logger line

Answer (score 1):

Winston logger returns a callback once the logging is done.

```
logger.error('Something went wrong!', () => {
    process.exit(1);
});
```